# Doing Calculations On a Two-Dimensional Array Using For Loop

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, numpy

I have a 9X51100 two-dimensional array (9 different datasets, 51,100 daily files) and I'm attempting to take 140 yearly averages of the data and append them to a new array. However, numpy.append needs two arguments and I end up appending more than I want to, I believe. Here's the code and the error I get.

```
import numpy as np

citydata = ['bcm2.a2.USC00101022.tmax.1960.2099.txt','bcm2.a2.USC00362682.tmax.1960.2099.txt','bcm2.a2.USC00415411.tmax.1960.2099.txt',
    'ccsm.a2.USC00101022.tmax.1960.2099.txt','ccsm.a2.USC00362682.tmax.1960.2099.txt','ccsm.a2.USC00415411.tmax.1960.2099.txt',
    'pcm.a2.USC00101022.tmax.1960.2099.txt','pcm.a2.USC00362682.tmax.1960.2099.txt','pcm.a2.USC00415411.tmax.1960.2099.txt']

year = np.asanyarray([(np.genfromtxt(item, skip_header=1)[:,0]) for item in citydata])
tmax = np.asanyarray([(np.genfromtxt(item, skip_header=1)[:,3]*(9./5.))+32 for item in citydata])

tmax_avg = np.zeros([9,140]) #initialize averaged array
for i in range(0,8,1):
    for yr in years: 
        toavg = (year == yr)
        tmax_avg[i,:] = np.append(tmax_avg,np.average(tmax[toavg]))



ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-a8a57d128124> in <module>()
  8     for yr in years:
  9         toavg = (year == yr)
 10-->      tmax_avg[i,:] = np.append(tmax_avg,np.average(tmax[toavg]))

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1261) into shape (140)
```

It also just seems to be only wanting to give me one 140-value array instead of a 9X140 array. Any help with either the append or looping problems? Thanks.

Comment: I know this has been mentioned before, but it really feels like you're trying to cram a `pandas` problem into a `numpy` framework.  Now with enough work, anything you can do with `pandas` you can do with `numpy` -- or with plain lists, for that matter -- but you're basically reimplementing `df.groupby("year").mean()`.  [Could also use `resample`.]

Comment: @DSM I hope to find the time to learn `pandas` sometime in the near future, but there never seem to be enough hours in the day. I know most of what's going on in `numpy` so that's why I continue to try and do most of my work with it.

Comment: I am not sure if I fully understand how your data is shaped, `year` and `tmax`, but would `tmax_avg[i][toavg] = np.average(tmax[toavg])` work. Or maybe `tmax_avg[i,j] = np.average(tmax[toavg])` with the for-loop replaced by `for j, yr in enumerate(years):`work?

Comment: @DJV it doesn't take long to learn. Think of it as just another library of convenient functions built on top of NumPy. With or without Pandas, what would be really helpful here is if you can add some example data for `year` and `tmax` or upload some short example files and link to them. As @Wicket says it's not clear how your data is shaped.

Comment: @Wicket Both year and tmax are 9X51100 arrays. Both contain daily data for 140 years worth of information (i.e. for year: 365 "1960"s "1961"s "1962"s and for tmax: a temperature value that corresponds to each day)

Comment: Are you taking some sort of max or average across the 9 datasets?  If not, I'd suggest loading one file at a time, process it, and then go on to the next.  Trying work with the 2d array complicates things unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

There is a relatively simple way of vectorizing your inner for loop using `np.unique` and `np.bincount`. If I read your code correctly, `year` is a `(9, 51100)` array of year labels, and `tmax` is a corresponding array of the same shape. You can do the following:

```
tmax_avg = []

count_years = np.unique(year).size

for loc in range(year.shape[0]):
    unq_year, unq_idx = np.unique(year[loc], return_inverse=True)
    unq_sum = np.bincount(unq_idx, weights=tmax[loc], minlength=count_years)
    unq_count = np.bincount(unq_idx, minlength=count_years)
    tmax_avg.append(unq_sum / unq_count)
tmax_avg  = np.vstack(tmax_avg)
```

You could get rid of the `loc` loop, but if you onbly have 9 sites it is probably not worth it.